# Unknown Class <XXX> in Interface Builder file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib

Hi initially I had an application where the app delegate defined the initial view controller to be an .xib of some other class. I deleted this class, its header and its .xib because I wanted the initial view controller to be of another class. 
In the app delegate class I deleted the original reference from the class I did not want and typed

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[NewClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewView" bundle:nil];
```

This works like a charm as the initial view is now "NewView". However the console gives me an error of the title above. I did a search on the whole project of the deleted class and there are no references to it. Furthermore I even deleted the actual files. Also, I deleted the simulator's cache.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the error says that there is an unknown class in IB. So look through all of your xib/storyboards. I am almost certain a view, controller, etc... (whatever your subclass was of), is declared using that class.

Searching all of your files or code for that class will not help since it is an Interface Builder error, so check around there.

Comment: I did a recursive grep for "RootViewController" on the source code's directory and the match showed up several times in the app's .pbxproj file. I deleted the lines containing the string and I still get the error. I grepped again and there are no matches.

Comment: is `RootViewController` the name of the class you deleted?

Comment: Yes the source, header, and xib, all had that prefix

Comment: Apparently this is some kind of bug, according to another post. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you attempted, but if you are still getting the error I am guessing it is either still located somewhere in a .xib or hanging onto it in its data somewhere. You could also attempt to clear derived data. That may help (organizer -> Projects -> 'select project' -> Derived Data - Delete)!

Comment: That did not work. In the info.plist file the "Main nib file base name" is set to MainWindow. I have also deleted MainWindow, yet the app still launches. I deleted the key and the app is just a black screen. If I set it to an existing .nib file I get an error of the class not being found, which is the epitome of irony.

Comment: After a few days I've finally figured it out. The Interface Builder file was set to MainWindow as stated above. Since, I had deleted this I thought the link would be broken and my main nib would be the one I had set it to be. Changing this in info.p-list returned an error. Thus I put back the MainWindow.xib only to find that it had "RootViewController" as a class for a navigation controller. I changed the class to the one I wanted and now there is no error! Thanks!